# Filepicker.io - video/* mimetype does not work in Chrome

Tags: filepicker.io

I've recently noticed a weirdness in Chrome where `.mov` files aren't being recognized as valid video files when picking. The following JSFiddle illustrates my point

http://jsfiddle.net/6aJBM/

You'll need to change the API key obviously. If open the above JSFiddle in Firefox, you can select both images and videos from the filesystem. If on the other hand you open it in Chrome, .mov files will be greyed out and therefore non-selectable. It seems like .mov files aren't registering as video files in Chrome. Has anyone ran into this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really silly, but if you replace `video/*` with:

```
video/avi, video/quicktime, video/mpeg, video/mp4, video/ogg, 
video/webm, video/x-ms-wmv, video/x-flv, video/x-matroska,
video/x-msvideo, video/x-dv
```

That will do the trick.

There's a odd bug/feature in Chrome that doesn't allow .mov to be selected. I'll have to look it up again, but iirc, chrome's behavior is considered strict, to the letter, compliance with the spec.

Answer (score 1):

On the [Filepicker blog](http://blog.filepicker.io/post/45899334267/filepicker-io-zencoder-adding-video-to-your-app-in) they suggested using the `extensions` filter instead of `mimetypes`.

```
var acceptedExtensions = [
  '3g2','3gp','3gp2','3gpp','3gpp2','aac','ac3','eac3','ec3','f4a',
  'f4b','f4v','flv','highwinds','m4a','m4b','m4r','m4v','mkv','mov',
  'mp3','mp4','oga','ogg','ogv','ogx','ts','webm','wma','wmv'
];
filepicker.pickAndStore({extensions: acceptedExtensions},...
```